# finite group scheme over char p, question about proof in Shatz book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$, and let $G$ be a finite connected group scheme over $k$. Let $FG$ be the frobenius twist of $G$, i.e. $FG=G \times_{\mathrm{Spec}\ k, Fr} \mathrm{Spec}\ k$, and let $f:G \to FG$ be the usual map that on the level of affine rings is given by $a \otimes \lambda \mapsto \lambda^pa$ [correction: $a^p\lambda$]for $a \in \mathcal{O}(G)$ and $\lambda \in k$.

Let $\Lambda = k[t]/t^2$ be the dual numbers. Why is $f(\Lambda): G(\Lambda) \to FG(\Lambda)$ the zero morphism?

This is claimed in Shatz's book *Profinite groups, algebra, and geometry.*

[image]
[image]

Comment: Since $G$ is connected you know that $G(k)$ is trivial, and similarly for its Frobenius twist $FG$. Since $\mathrm{Lie}(H)=\ker(H(\lambda)\to H(k))$ we deduce that $G(\Lambda)$ and $FG(\Lambda)$ are the Lie algebras for $G$ and $FG$. Show that the Frobenius, being the pth power map, induces the multiplication by $p$ map on the Lie algebras which is zero since you're in char p? Also, is your relative Frobenius map wrong? It should be the pth power on the other term?

Comment: @AlexYoucis ah, thanks I have the p-power on the wrong part,it should be on the a ... and yeah then it makes sense that it reduces to  multiplication by p on the Lie algebras and so is zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to turn my comment into an answer (let me know if more clarification is needed).

Since $G$ and $FG$ are connected we know that $G(k)=FG(k)=\{e\}$. Now, for any finite flat group scheme $H$ over $k$ we have that $\mathrm{Lie}(H)=\ker(H(k[\varepsilon])\to H(k))$ where $k[\varepsilon]\to k$ is the unique $k$-algebra map. In particular, if $H$ is connected then $\mathrm{Lie}(H)=H(k[\varepsilon])$. So, if $\mathrm{Frob}:G\to FG$ were injective then, in particular, the induced map $G(k[\varepsilon])\to FG(k[\varepsilon])$ is injective. Or, in other words, we'd have that the map $\mathrm{Lie}(G)\to\mathrm{Lie}(FG)$ is injective. But, it's not hard to see that the Frobenius map induces the zero map on Lie algebras (since $da^p=p da^{p-1}=0$ since the Lie algebra is a $k$-space).